Populate nested relations in MikroORM
I am using NestJS 10 with MikroORM 6.3
I have the following entities
Entity()
export class CertificateEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Property()
  name: string;

  @Property()
  tyoe: string;

  @OneToMany(() => CertificateModuleEntity, (module) => module.certificate, {
    cascade: [Cascade.ALL]
  })
  modules: CertificateModuleEntity[];
}

@Entity()
export class CertificateModuleEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Property()
  order: number;

  @Property()
  title: string;


  @ManyToOne(() => CertificateEntity)
  certificate: CertificateEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => CertificateQuestionEntity, (certificate) => certificate.module, {
    cascade: [Cascade.ALL]
  })
  questions: CertificateQuestionEntity[];

}

@Entity()
export class CertificateQuestionEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Property()
  order: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => CertificateModuleEntity)
  module: CertificateModuleEntity;

  @Property()
  content: string;
}

I want to issue a findOne as I only want to find a unique instance while populating the relations, both modules and questions
So far
this.certificateRepo.findOne(
  {
    type
  },
  {
    populate: ['modules', 'modules.questions']
  }
);

does not return nested relations

What version are you on? What queries do you see with debug mode enabled? How does your ORM config look like?

@MartinAdámek I have included the version and made some corrections, Thank you,

i asked about the exact version, so what 6.3.x are you on?

and i cant see answers to the other 2 questions :]
